# Share data between native app and mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, web-applications

I have a native application which installed on a client mobile device. 
Other than that, I have a web application that this client can access via a mobile browser.

I would like to sync and pass information (such as identifiers or other user data) between the application and the web browser.
Is there any WebAPI that can help me do so?

I found the `getInstalledRelatedApps` that can indicate me whether my application installed or not, but what about sharing an information between those two? Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Are you planning to transfer data in both ways (www <--> mobile)  or only one way (www -> mobile OR mobile -> www)?

Comment: Mostly between the mobile app to the browser

Comment: So you can call JavaScript code from `WebView`

Comment: Nice one, but what if the application won't be a webview app?

Comment: Nothing. You can call some JS method on `WebView`, e.g. javascript:console.log('some super info")` or `Print.postMessage('info')`. But it's not necessary to make it visible (or make it `1px x 1px`)

Answer (score 0):

What frameworks are you using? Can I consider that you are using Node JS, React and React Native?

You could use express in the backend to create your own API, call it on the Frontend/Mobile with Axios, and then you could pass the parameters by setting them on the route. I.E. let's say that you want to pass on the tea ID from the mobile app to the web app so you can see them on your navigator:

```
// BACKEND
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/tea/:teaId', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params);
});

module.exports = routes;


// MOBILE
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://your-url-here.com/',
});

let teaID = 22;

function sendToWeb() {
  Linking.openURL(`https://your-url-here.com/tea/${teaID}`)
}
```

You can also pass Header Authorization in case that you want the user to be logged on and skip the login step or something related to it.

[Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

[About Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

I hope that this can help you a bit! And sorry if it seems confusing, it's my first time trying to answer a question!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure though how you meant that I will get the data on the mobile browser?

Comment: The data will be passed through the URI, the part right after the 'https://your-url-here.com/'. By creating routes you will let your application know what kind of behavior you want it to have (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and what is required to that parameter. IE: the route 'https://your-url-here.com/tea/:teaID' means that in order to acess that route, it is required to have a number after the tea, which would be the teaID in this example.
So by redirecting the user to 'https://your-url-here.com/tea/5', your route would understand that the desired ID is 5!

Comment: You can think of routes as a different approach to manipulate the data of your DB other than SQL Queries!

Comment: But how can you make the mobile app and the mobile browser send the requests to the same URL?

Comment: By using routes, you are basically creating your own API. You could think about it as running the github api, for example. It doesn't matter if you're connecting throught your phone or your web, it should return the same value.